# Lock-free guard for synchronized acquire/release

Tags: java, multithreading, mutex, critical-section, lock-free

I have a shared tempfile resource that is divided into chunks of 4K (or some such value). Each 4K in the file is represented by an index starting from zero.  For this shared resource, I track the 4K chunk indices in use and always return the lowest indexed 4K chunk not in use, or -1 if all are in use.

This ResourceSet class for the indices has a public acquire and release method, both of which use synchronized lock whose duration is about like that of generating 4 random numbers (expensive, cpu-wise).

Therefore as you can see from the code that follows, I use an AtomicInteger "counting semaphore" to prevent a large number of threads from entering the critical section at the same time on acquire(), returning -1 (not available right now) if there are too many threads.

Currently, I am using a constant of 100 for the tight CAS loop to try to increment the atomic integer in acquire, and a constant of 10 for the maximum number of threads to then allow into the critical section, which is long enough to create contention.  My question is, what should these constants be for a moderate to highly loaded servlet engine that has several threads trying to get access to these 4K chunks?

```
public class ResourceSet {

    // ??? what should this be
    // maximum number of attempts to try to increment with CAS on acquire
    private static final int    CAS_MAX_ATTEMPTS = 50;

    // ??? what should this be
    // maximum number of threads contending for lock before returning -1 on acquire
    private static final int    CONTENTION_MAX = 10;

    private AtomicInteger        latch = new AtomicInteger(0);

    ... member variables to track free resources

    private boolean aquireLatchForAquire ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CAS_MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {
            int val = latch.get();
            if (val == -1)
                throw new AssertionError("bug in ResourceSet");        // this means more threads than can exist on any system, so its a bug!
            if (!latch.compareAndSet(val, val+1))
                continue;
            if (val < 0 || val >= CONTENTION_MAX) {
                latch.decrementAndGet();
                // added to fix BUG that comment pointed out, thanks!
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void aquireLatchForRelease ()
    {
        do {
            int val = latch.get();
            if (val == -1)
                throw new AssertionError("bug in ResourceSet");    // this means more threads than can exist on any system, so its a bug!
            if (latch.compareAndSet(val, val+1))
                return;
        } while (true);
    }

    public ResourceSet (int totalResources)
    {
        ... initialize
    }

    public int acquire (ResourceTracker owned)
    {        
        if (!aquireLatchForAquire())
            return -1;

        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                ... algorithm to compute minimum free resoource or return -1 if all in use
                return resourceindex;
            }
        } finally {
            latch.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    public boolean release (ResourceIter iter)
    {
        aquireLatchForRelease();
        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                ... iterate and release all resources
            }
        } finally {
            latch.decrementAndGet();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code to share?

Comment: I just added the code to show what I am doing.

Comment: Please write to the point and precise.

Comment: isn't this code bugged once contention_max is reached because the method will return false and then decrement is never called.

Comment: @benmmurphy -- great call, saved me a lot of pain in testing!

Comment: Why not using AtomicInteger to manage access to the indices of the chunk file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writting a good and performant spinlock is actually pretty complicated and requires a good understanding of memory barriers. Merely picking a constant is not going to cut it and will definitely not be portable. Google's gperftools has [an example](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/source/browse/trunk/src/base/spinlock.cc) that you can look at but is probably way more complicated then what you'd need.

If you really want to reduce contention on the lock, you might want to consider using a more fine-grained and optimistic scheme. A simple one could be to divide your chunks into n groups and associate a lock with each group (also called stripping). This will help reduce contention and increase throughput but it won't help reduce latency. You could also associate an AtomicBoolean to each chunk and CAS to acquire it (retry in case of failure). Do be careful when dealing with lock-free algorithms because they tend to be tricky to get right. If you do get it right, it could considerably reduce the latency of acquiring a chunk.

Note that it's difficult to propose a more fine-grained approach without knowing what your chunk selection algorithm looks like. I also assume that you really do have a performance problem (it's been profiled and everything).

While I'm at it, your spinlock implementation is flawed. You should never spin directly on a CAS because you're spamming memory barriers. This will be incredibly slow with any serious amount of contention (related to the [thundering-herd problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thundering_herd_problem)). A minimum would be to first check the variable for availability before your CAS (simple if on a no barrier read will do). Even better would be to not have all your threads spinning on the same value. This should avoid the associated cache-line from ping-pong-ing between your cores.

Note that I don't know what type of memory barriers are associated with atomic ops in Java so my above suggestions might not be optimal or correct.

Finally, [The Art Of Multiprocessor Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123705916) is a fun book to read to get better acquainted with all the non-sense I've been spewing in this answer.

Comment: Your answer leads me to wonder, if my CAS loop causes memory barriers to become a performance problem, then how does java.util.concurrent.Semaphore do their spin locks for decrementAndGet, etc.

Comment: I checked the JDK source code and getAndIncrement uses a CAS loop just like mine except that it is never ending.

Comment: (Wish I could edit comments after more than 5 min.)  I meant that AtomicInteger getAndIncrement() uses the same CAS loop like mine except it is infinite.  So if my CAS loop causes memory barrier spams, then so does AtomicInteger's CAS loops for increments and decrements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's necessary to forge your own Lock class for this scenario. As JDK provided ReentrantLock, which also leverage CAS instruction during lock acquire. The performance should be pretty good when compared with your personal Lock class.

Comment: A ReentrantLock would not suffice for this problem.  A Semaphore with 10 permits would simulate my code, but I would not have control over the CAS loop.  The Semaphore class'es CAS loop would loop until lock is acquired.

Comment: Yeah, ReentrantLock won't do the trick. Sorry for my misunderanding. On the other hand, Semaphone calls LockSupport.park(this) to suspend current thread if the permits are used up. This is the right behavior in my mind, cause it can save CPU from busy-retrying to get the permit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Semaphore`'s `tryAcquire` method if you want your threads to balk on `no resource available`.

I for one would simply substitute your `synchronized` keyword with a `ReentrantLock` and use the `tryLock()` method on it. If you want to let your threads wait a bit, you can use `tryLock(timeout)` on the same class. Which one to choose and what value to use for timeout, needs to be determined by way of a performance test.

Creating an explicit gate seems as you seem to be doing seems unnecessary to me. I'm not saying that it can never help, but IMO it's more likely to actually hurt performance, and it's an added complication for sure. So unless you have an performance issue around here (based on a test you did) and you found that this kind of gating helps, I'd recommend to go with the simplest implementation.

Comment: I checked the JDK code for Semaphore.tryAcquire(long timeout, TimeUnit) and it calls System.nanoTime() in its tightest loop when it is unable to immediately get the lock.  I profiled System.nanoTime() on my system and it took half a microsecond, whereas the critical section that I'm trying to protect with CAS is about 10 times faster than System.nanoTime!  Thus I think Semaphore and ReentrantLock have way too much overhead.

Comment: @AndyNuss: In fact that may make sense as it usually makes sense to yield the CPU to other threads when you can't do a successful CAS for a while. On the other hand, if your critical section is that fast then it's probably wrong to use the balking pattern to begin with. Why not simply use `synchronized` and let the threads wait until they get the stuff they want?